# Where is benchmarking in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I remember seeing benchmarking in Google Analytics in the past - in fact I opted in to it on several sites. However, I can't find any more. The [Analytics blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/03/benchmarking-now-available-plus.html) shows it should be under the Visitors section but it's not there.

Is it still available? If it has been removed, does anyone know why? I can't find any info on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was [re-introduced in September 2014](https://econsultancy.com/blog/65422-google-analytics-benchmarking-is-back-here-s-what-you-need-to-know#i.29593xmflf5yv7) after it was discontinued back in 2011.

[Google's official blog post](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/new-benchmarking-reports-help-twiddy.html) on the re-introduction explains where to find it:

> Benchmarking reports can be found in the “Audience” section of the reporting interface [...] If you want to join in, simply check the “Share anonymously with Google and others” box in the Account Settings tab of your account admin page.

[image: Check the “Share anonymously with Google and others” box to enable to benchmarking tool.]

Answer (score 2):

After further research it appears the Benchmarking feature is being replaced/upgraded. However, it's currently in a transition period where they got rid of the old benchmarking but haven't released the new one yet... [This blog post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/03/evolution-of-analytics-benchmarking.html) has some details.

Comment: Answer [now out of date](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72049/2096).